# Fit a GMM to a 3D histogram in scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, mixture-model

The mixture model code in scikit-learn works for a list individual data points, but what if you have a histogram? That is, I have a density value for every voxel, and I want the mixture model to approximate it. Is this possible? I suppose one solution would be to sample values from this histogram, but that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: welcome to slashdot! i don't know much about scikit, but if you can post some more details, including maybe some sample code for discussion, you may get more responses.

Comment: It depends on the application. Do you actually need the locations and standard deviations of the gaussian mixture model? Are you using it for classification? If you really need a Gaussian mixture model you could use a multi-peak Gaussian fit to approximate the histogram with a Gaussian mixture model. But, that wouldn't be the easiest route if you simply want smooth interpolation, in that case something like bicubic interpolation may be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Scikit-learn has extensive utilities and algorithms for kernel density estimation, which is specifically centered around inferring distributions from things like histograms. See the documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/density.html) for some examples. If you have no expectations for the distribution of your data, KDE might be a more general approach.

Answer (score 0):

For 2D histogram `Z` (your 2D array of voxels)

```py
import numpy as np
# create the co-ordinate values
X, Y = np.mgrid[0:Z.shape[0], 0:Z.shape[1]]

# artificially create a list of points from your histogram
data_points = []
for x, y, z in zip(X.ravel(), Y.ravel(), Z.ravel()):
    # add the data point / voxel (x, y) as many times as it occurs
    # in the histogram
    for iz in z:
        data_points.append((x, y))

# now fit your GMM
from sklearn.mixture import GMM
gmm = GMM()
gmm.fit(data_points)
```

Though, as @Kyle Kastner points out, there are better methods for achieving this. For a start, your histogram will be 'binned' which will already loose you some resolution. Can you get hold of the raw data before it was binned?